# Linq - 2 tables - Sum

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, group-by, sum

Asiento
    ********
    Id_Asiento integer key
    Fecha date

```
It_Asiento
**********
Id_Asiento integer Forenkey
Importe float
```

I wan to do This SQL Query with Linq

```
select Asiento.Id_Asiento, Asiento.Fecha, Sum(It_Asiento.Importe) 
From Asiento 
join It_Asiento 
on Asiento.Id_Asiento = It_Asiento.Id_Asiento
and It_Asiento.Importe > 0
group by Asiento.Id_Asiento, Asiento.Fecha
```

**On my DataBase boot tables have a relation, so on C# / Linq i don't need to make a join, right??**

I try this, but don't work

```
IQueryable listAsientos = from it_a in dc_Asientos.It_Asientos
                          where it_a.importe > 0
                          group it_a by it_a.id_asto, it_a.Asiento.fecha
                          **//¿it_a.ASiento.Fecha??????**
                          into resultado
                          select new
                          { 
                              id_asto = resultado.Key,
                              **/¿¿¿¿¿fecha = it.a.Asiento.Fecha?????**
                              suma = resultado.Sum(it => it.importe)
                          };
```

Can somebody help me?
SORRY for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Isn;t `resultado` an `It_Asientos` object? So you should use

```
id_asto = resultado.Key.Id_asto,
fecha = resultado.Key.fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query may solve your problem

```
IQueryable listAsientos = from it_a in dc_Asientos.It_Asientos
                      where it_a.importe > 0
                      group it_a by new { it_a.id_asto, it_a.Asiento.fecha }
                      into resultado
                      select new
                      { 
                          id_asto = resultado.Key.id_asto,
                          suma = resultado.Sum(it => it.importe)
                      };
```